# req.isAuthenticated() returning false all the time in passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, basic-authentication, passport-local

I have passport setup in express and req.isAuthenticated() always returning due to wrong order of code in index.js. I am not able to figure out the order in which I have to write code , I searched for other answers in stackoverflow and I couldnt figure out the right order since my code has different dependencies please help . This is my index.js file :

```
const winston = require("winston");
const express = require("express");
const config = require("config");
const app = express();
const passport = require('passport');
const flash    = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());








app.use(session({ 
  secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./services/passport')(passport);

require("./startup/db")();


app.use(flash());



require("./startup/logging")();
require("./startup/cors")(app);
require("./startup/routes")(app);

require("./startup/config")();
//require("./startup/validation")();



const port = process.env.PORT || config.get("port");
const server = app.listen(port, () =>
  winston.info(`Listening on port ${port}...`)
);

module.exports = server;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling `req.isAuthenticated()` ?

Comment: I got it . it was problem with express-session . it was not setting cookies. So i used cookie-session module and everything works well

Comment: glad it worked :)

Comment: yeah thanks man :D